# Getting an arrays of equal length from numpy histogram or plotting the uneven array

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, histogram, probability

This might be a simple question but I can't figure it out.

Say I have a data set such as this:

```
180.0
170.9
-180.0
0.00
50.0
...
```

I have been using the `numpy.histogram` function in order to get the values of the probabilities in the range of -180 to 180 using

```
probs, ang = np.histogram(angles, bins=360, range=(-180,180))
```

However it returns a hist array and bin_edges array that have unequal lengths

> Returns:
>
> hist : array
>
> The values of the histogram. See normed and weights for a description of the possible semantics.
>
> bin_edges : array of dtype float
>
> Return the bin edges (length(hist)+1).

How can I get probabilities of my data set in which each number in my range(-180 to 180 including zero) have a probability associated with it for example:

```
range prob
-180  0.70
-170  0.01
-160  0.01
```

I need the probabilities to match up with the ranges

I did it in matlab like this

```
[probas, angles] = hist(x, -180:10:180, 1.0);
```

which seems similar but wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bins are equally spaced already.

To get probabilities out of an histogram you have to normalize (i.e. divide by the sum over all histogram values):

```
probs = probs / np.sum(probs)
```